# Is it possible to block other runnables while executing the first one, using ExecutorService in Java?

Tags: java, executorservice, java-threads

I'm trying to process a relatively huge `Stream` of `List` in multiple threads, using an `ExecutorService`. The method looks something like this.

```
public void initMigration() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try (Stream<List<Record4<Integer, Integer, String, byte[]>>> streamOfLists = getStreamOfLists()) {            
        streamOfLists.forEach(record4List -> {
            Runnable runnable = () -> {
                try {
                    final List<Attachment> attachments = RecordProcessor.prepareAttachmentsToPost(record4List);
                    LOGGER.info("Invoking POST with payload {}", attachments);
                    Collection<UploadLink> uploadLinks = restClient.postAttachments(attachments);
                    restClient.processUploadLinksAndUpload(RecordProcessor.recordsIntoPojo(record4List), uploadLinks);
                } catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
            executorService.submit(runnable);
        });
    }
    LOGGER.info("Shutting down the ExecutorService");
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do here is, for each `List` in the `Stream`, a `Runnable` is being created and submitted to the `ExecutorService`. It seems to be working alright. But, what I really wanna do now, is to see if there's any way I can make the `ExecutorService` run the first `Runnable` obtained from the first `List` in the `Stream` while blocking other `Runnables` until
its execution, and continue running other `Runnables` (in parallel) after that. Could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take first Runnable, execute it, and only then submit other Runnables.

```
    try (Stream<List<Record4<Integer, Integer, String, byte[]>>> streamOfLists = getStreamOfLists()) {
        Iterator<List<Record4<Integer, Integer, String, byte[]>>> it = streamOfLists.iterator();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            List<Record4<Integer, Integer, String, byte[]>> list = it.next();
            Runnable runnable = new MyRunnable(record4List);
            runnable.run();
        }
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            List<Record4<Integer, Integer, String, byte[]>> list = it.next();
            Runnable runnable = new MyRunnable(record4List);
            executorService.submit(runnable);
        }
    }
```

where

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    Record4<Integer, Integer, String, byte[]> record4List;

    MyRunnable(Record4<Integer, Integer, String, byte[]> record4List) {
        this.record4List = record4List;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final List<Attachment> attachments = RecordProcessor.prepareAttachmentsToPost(record4List);
            LOGGER.info("Invoking POST with payload {}", attachments);
            Collection<UploadLink> uploadLinks = restClient.postAttachments(attachments);
            restClient.processUploadLinksAndUpload(RecordProcessor.recordsIntoPojo(record4List), uploadLinks);
        } catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

[@Alexei's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720902/139985) is (IMO) the correct way to solve this problem.  Don't block the runnables.  Instead submit the runnables when the preconditions for running them have already been satisfied.

The problem with having one runnable block others is that you are liable to clog up the executor's thread pool with tasks that are blocked waiting for another task to finish.  Indeed, if the thread pool is bounded, you could even get into a situation where all of the threads are in this state and the executor is unable to start the task that will unblock them all.  Result: deadlock!

---

If you *still* wanted to block the runnables (in spite of the above), then you could implement it using a `CountDownLatch`.

1. Prior to instantiating the `Runnable`s, create a `CountDownLatch` instance with an initial counter of `1`.  This instance must be shared by all of the `Runnable`s.
2. Code one `Runnable` so that it fetches a `List`, processes it, then calls `latch.count()`;
3. Code a second `Runnable` to call `latch.await()` and then fetch and process a `List`.
4. Submit one task using the first `Runnable` and the remainder using the second one.